# Modification of objects in constant expression contexts

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```
struct S
{
  constexpr S(){};
  constexpr S(const S &r) { *this = r; };
  constexpr S &operator=(const S &) { return *this; };
};

int main()
{
  S s1{};
  constexpr S s2 = s1; // OK
}
```

The above program is [well-formed](https://godbolt.org/z/ocd4xodnj) but I'm expecting it to be ill-formed, because [[expr.const]/(5.16)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5.16) says:

> An expression `E` is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of
> `E`, following the rules of the abstract machine ([intro.execution]),
> would evaluate one of the following:
>
> - [..]
> - (5.16) a modification of an object ([expr.ass], [expr.post.incr], [expr.pre.incr]) unless it is applied to a non-volatile lvalue of
>   literal type that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began
>   within the evaluation of `E`;
> - [..]

Given the expression `E` is `s1`. The expression `E` evaluates a modification of the object `*this`. The modification is applied to the non-volatile lvalue `*this` which is of literal type, and this lvalue refers to a non-volatile object which is `s1` *but* the lifetime of `s1` does not begin within the evaluation of `E`: That's the lifetime of the object `s1` began *before* the evaluation of the expression `E`.

So I'm expecting the program is ill-formed because the "unless" part does not satisfy which means, to me, that the expression `E` is not a core constant expression. So what I'm missing here? Am I misreading (5.16)?

Comment: There are no modifications here

Comment: @LanguageLawyer - What about `*this = r;`? This is `[expr.ass]`!

Comment: It is just a function call (and the function called also does not perform modifications)

Comment: _This is [expr.ass]!_ This is not. This is [over.match.oper]

Comment: See also https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/defns.access#sentence-1 and https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/defns.access#sentence-2 (this claim is not 100% accurate, but is fine for now)

Comment: Thanks, @LanguageLawyer for this so good info - Can you let me ask some simple questions in a chat?

Comment: Ask in comments xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Language Lawyer points out, there are no modifications in your program, however even if the constructor did modify `s2`, this wouldn't necessarily make the program ill-formed, because:

> In any `constexpr` variable declaration, the full-expression of the initialization shall be a constant expression ([expr.const]).

-- [[dcl.constexpr]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#7.sentence-3)

The constructor is allowed to modify `s2` because the lifetime of `s2` begins within the full-expression of the initialization, and only the full-expression of the initialization is required to be a constant expression (not the initializer in isolation).

*Addendum:* The only modifications that are relevant for [expr.const]/5.16 are modifications to scalar objects. This is because only modifications to scalar objects actually result in *accesses* to the memory of the abstract machine (see also [defns.access](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.defs#defns.access)). When I say the constructor is allowed to modify `s2`, I mean the constructor is allowed to modify scalar subobjects of `s2`.